# Python pytest in Azure DevOps - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pytest, devops

I have my DevOps pipeline which is using pytest to execute unit tests found in Python code.

I'm using a root folder called "core" for the main python functionality, and reference it using the following format:

```
import unittest
from core.objects.paragraph import Paragraph
from core.objects.sentence import Sentence
```

Running this locally (python -m pytest) works correctly and executes all of the tests.

However, everytime I run this from Azure DevOps I get the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

I have no idea why this is happening ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

For reference, this is my YAML build definition

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python310:
      python.version: '3.10.7'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
  displayName: 'Use Python $(python.version)'

- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- script: |
    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
  displayName: 'Install pytest'

- script: |
    python -m pytest --junitxml=$(Build.StagingDirectory)/Testoutput.xml
  workingDirectory: 'tests'
  displayName: 'Test with PyTest'
```

Once the execution has finished, this is the error message I'm seeing:

```
____________ ERROR collecting test_objects/test_paragraph_object.py ____________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/vsts/work/1/s/tests/test_objects/test_paragraph_object.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.7/x64/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test_objects/test_paragraph_object.py:2: in <module>
    from core.objects.paragraph import Paragraph
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
------------ generated xml file: /home/vsts/work/1/a/Testoutput.xml ------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure the directory`/home/vsts/work/1/s/tests/`has a `__init__.py`file.

Comment: Thank you! 

It seems a whole bunch of folders (including core ) didn't have one of those. Frustrating that everything executed correctly locally, but all working in DevOps now

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem. My project was structured as following:

```
dags/
├─ deployments/
│  ├─ item/
│  ├─ users/
│  │  ├─ dag_users.py
├─ utils1/
│  ├─ helpers.py
├─ utils2/
│  ├─ helpers2.py
tests/
├─ test_dag_integrity.py
```

From the pytest perspective, it is called src structure (as shown in the pytest documentation https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#integrating-with-setuptools-python-setup-py-test-pytest-runner)

So, I added a file into root folder called

`pyproject.toml`

Containing the following content

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = "dags"
```

The structure after add toml file

```
dags/
tests/
pyproject.toml
```

This solve the problem.